# Exclude own samples from healthkit queries

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit, hksamplequery

I'm writing an app that amongst other things, reads weight samples from HealthKit.
I'm also writing samples.
I'm trying to read the latest sample that isn't mine:

```
NSPredicate* non_fdct = [NSCompoundPredicate notPredicateWithSubpredicate:[HKQuery predicateForObjectsFromSource:[HKSource defaultSource]]];
NSSortDescriptor *last = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate ascending:NO];
HKSampleQuery* query = [[HKSampleQuery alloc] initWithSampleType:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass] predicate:non_fdct limit:1 sortDescriptors:@[last] resultsHandler:^(HKSampleQuery *query, NSArray *results, NSError *error) {  ... };
```

But I'm getting my own samples if they are the latest samples.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The way you have constructed the `non_fdct` predicate is not quite correct.  Try this instead:

`NSPredicate *non_fdct = [NSPredicate predicateFromString:@"%K != %@", HKPredicateKeyPathSource, [HKSource defaultSource]];`

Comment: If that's true than I totally missed the way these predicates should work.. I'm currently filtering by my bundle ID, will comment / accept this once I test it, 10x!